# What's the cleanest way to add a hook on certain path changes?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'd like to add a hook function when the "path namespace" changes. For example, when the router goes from *myapp/**fields**/9837278993* to *myapp/**lists**/183727856*. Of course I could use some regex conditional logic in the main `onBeforeAction` hook. The more abstract logic would be "when namespace goes from **fields** to **any except fields** run the hook. What are your suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track wanting to abstract the logic away from the router layer (makes switching routers much easier!). The problem is getting the data context before it changes.

To accomplish this, I'd recommend turning your `Router.go` line into a function. Chances are this is inside an event, so the IR reactive `current()` won't hurt you here.

```
function changePath(path) {
  if (path !== 'fields' && Router.current().route.name === 'fields') {
    //do stuff
  }
  Router.go(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with my own fully generic solution, using the **reactive** var `Router.current().location.get()` mixed with the `Tracker.autorun` function. So It's 100% independant of Router configuration, which I think is a good thing. Written in coffeescript.

Trivial to use :

```
Meteor.startup ->  
  RouterTransitions.register('/lists/' ,null,-> console.log("Switching from lists to any"))
```

Expected behaviour :

- When the route changes from `/lists/*` to `/(*)` where `(*)!='lists/'`, the `hook` function is run.
- You can register as many transitions as you want from the same origin, as long as the destination is not a subpath of the origin (for example : `from /lists/ to /lists/1864f` will not trigger the hook). However the origin can be a subpath of the destination.

Here is the source :

```
class RouterTransitions

  #could be any sequence of characters with at least one forbidden in URL standards (RFC 3986, section 2 characters)
  WILDCARD:'>>'

  constructor:->
    Tracker.autorun =>
      newPath=Router.current()?.location.get().path
      if @_oldPath!=newPath
        @_matchingDestinations.forEach (destinations) =>
          origin=destinations.origin
          Object.keys(destinations.targets).forEach (key) =>
            if !newPath.match("#{origin}.*")&&(key==@WILDCARD or newPath.match("#{key}.*"))
              #call the hook
              destinations.targets[key]()
      @_matchingOrigins =Object.keys(@dictionnary).filter (origin) => newPath.match("#{origin}.*")
      @_matchingDestinations = @_matchingOrigins.map (key)=> {
      targets:@dictionnary[key]
      origin:key
      }
      @_oldPath=newPath


  ###
  @param {String} origin : the namespace of the incoming path, null for any match. Origin can be a subset of destination.
  @param {String} destination : the namespace of the forthcoming path, null for any match. Important! destination cannot be a subset of origin
  @param {String} hook : the callback to be run on matching conditions
  ###
  register:(origin,destination,hook) =>
    origin=origin||@WILDCARD
    destination=destination||@WILDCARD
    if @dictionnary[origin]
      @dictionnary[origin][destination]=hook
    else
      hooks=@dictionnary[origin]={}
      hooks[destination]=hook

  #A simple dict with keys='origin' and values plain objects with destinations mapped to hooks
  dictionnary:{}

  _oldPath:'/'

  _matchingDestinations:[]

  _matchingOrigins:[]

window.RouterTransitions=new RouterTransitions()
```